# WordPress - SQL Query Optimization

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Is it better to add the condition **(meta_key = 'items')** to my query or this is not necessary.

I told myself that by limiting the research to only if meta_key equal to items will optimize my SQL Query.

```
global $wpdb;
$value = 'my_vaue';     
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE (meta_key = 'items') AND (meta_value LIKE '%%$value%%')");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key = 'items' AND
      meta_value LIKE '%%$value%%';
```

(Why do you have two `'%'` in the pattern?  That is equivalent to one.)

Your question is not one of performance, but of functionality.  The alternative is:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%%$value%%';
```

The first searches through the "items" for your value.  The second searches through *all* rows in the table.  Use the one that best matches the functionality you want.

Unless "items" are very rare in the table, both queries will do a full table scan.  The performance will probably be dominated by reading the data.  However, `like` is a bit expensive so the first version might be a wee bit faster.